# Is it possible to install a device driver without having the device?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, windows-embedded-7

I need to install drivers for a Startech WiFi dongle, but I don't actually have one to hand.

Any instructions I've found on installing driver software involves going into the Device Manager and right-clicking on the device and going for there, but of course if I don't have the device then it won't appear there.

I've tried, "Add Legacy Hardware" => "Have Disk..." in the device manager, which lets me browse to my driver files, but after I browse to the driver file and click "OK", the list of network adapters is blank.

If I run the setup application that came with the device, then it also installs the utility, which I don't want.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Install - no. Add to OS's driver library - yes. Simply install all .INF files from driver folder (right-click - install). Ignore all error messages if occured.

Answer (score 9):

from Administrative command prompt

```
pnputil -a e:\foldername\driver.inf
```

You will need to extract the driver until the *.inf file is visible.